# linking firebase firestore with laravel

Tags: laravel, google-cloud-firestore, xampp, grpc

I want to test Firestore with laravel. But before i can use it, I need a couple of tools.

I'm stuck on gRPC. I installed it, it's working on my windows and I can install Firestore with Composer, but I can't get it to work with XAMPP. When I load a page I get:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\GoogleException: The requested client requires the gRPC extension. Please see https://cloud.google.com/php/grpc for installation instructions. in /vendor/google/cloud-core/src/ClientTrait.php:75 Stack trace: #0 /vendor/google/cloud-firestore/src/FirestoreClient.php(115): Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient->requireGrpc() #1 /app/firebase.php(18): Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient->__construct() #2 /app/firebase.php(21): App\initialize() #3 /template.php(688): require_once('/Applications/X...') #4 /template.php(647): load_template('/Applications/X...', true) #5 /App in
>   /vendor/google/cloud-core/src/ClientTrait.php on line 75

Answer (score 0):

It may be the case that the gRPC extention is not enabled on the `php.ini` file, you can enable it by:

- On PHP version 7.2 and up: add `extension=grpc` on the `php.ini` file
- On older PHP versions: add `extension=php_grpc.dll` on the `php.ini` file

And then restart XAMPP and the extension will be activated as showed in `phpinfo()` and it should work.

If this does not work, a workaround for the issue is to download the gRPC DLL and add it to your project's extentions manually. You can download the latest version on the [PECL repository for gRPC](https://pecl.php.net/package/gRPC) (Choose a stable version), and extract the `php_grpc.dll` file to the extensions folder in XAMPP, which the path you can find on the `php.ini`.

After that, enable the extetion as described earlier and restart XAMPP again.

Let me know if this fixed your issue.

Comment: not when I add the extension in php.ini the server does not work any more and also the commands to composer in laravel, and also when I downloaded manually in PECL the last version I do not find the php_grpc.dll

Comment: on the download tab there is a .tgz file and a dll option, if you click on the dll it will take you to a second page with several links for download a zip file that contains the dll you want, let me know if it works with that dll.